# Django cursor not insert/update queries

Tags: sql-server, django

Here is my code for cursor execution.

```
from django.db import connection       
cursor = connection.cursor()    
cursor.execute("Some insert/Update query")
```

Cursor execute successfully because it returns output as inserted ID. But its not showing inserted values in database.

I tried to close connection but no success.

```
cursor.close()
Connection.close()
```

If I tried to use  `Connection.commit()` but it gives error.

```
Exception Type: TransactionManagementError
Exception Value: This code isn't under transaction management
```

One Amazing behavior I found.
If I use Connection.commit then it give error but it insert row successfully.
without connection.commit it neither gives error and nor insert row in database.

I am using MS-SQL server as back-end connecting using sqlserver_ado.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of goggling finally came to this solution.

Use `@transaction.commit_manually` before the view call.

For more details : [Commit_Manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually)

Answer (score 0):

your django version should lower than 1.6

you should commit it manually
use

```
django.db.transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

or

```
import django
if not django.get_version().startswith('1.6'):
    # when version=1.5 not auto-commit, commit here
    django.db.transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```